# How to get all applicable methods, including extension methods, for a NamedTypeSymbol in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, roslyn

I am trying to extend the Roslyn compiler with additional syntax that unlike LINQ has to know beforehand if `Select`, `Zip`, etc. can be applied to the type. I am doing this in the binder, since I am simplifying nested syntax nodes into a single bound expression. `GetMembers` on the `NamedTypeSymbol` returns only the actual members of the type. How can I get the list of extension methods that are defined for that type and are accessible at this place in the code?

Comment: Have you seen this code sample? https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/roslynfaq/csharp/#faq5

Comment: @WouterdeKort thanks, but that's a bit different. This snippet compiles the source first, while I am extending the Roslyn compiler itself. Thanks, anyway, I'll take a look at which step the `SemanticModel` is produced.

Comment: Beware that an extension like that can cause circular dependencies in the bind phase, if you use your syntax to produce a type-inferred expression with these names as delegate members of anonymous types, or as regular members, and use that inferred type in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work on the `Binder` level or not, but if you can get a hold of the `Compilation` object, then you can query its `GlobalNamespace` property, which is "The root namespace that contains all namespaces and types defined in source code or in referenced metadata, merged into a single namespace hierarchy." From this you can get the (top level) type declarations and then you can simply look for any extension method that matches the type that you are processing.